# Edge browser crashes after "No Such Window exception" with robotframework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, microsoft-edge

I am using Edge web driver with robotframework (selenium2library) on windows 10 VM. When I run the test Edge browser is invoked test are getting executed too but somewhere in the middle (keywords: Wait until element is visible/wait until page contain element) I start getting the error "No Such Window Exception". There are no multiple windows but just a single window. Did someone face these kind of problem? This keyword is already being used for same page and it worked fore few tests but suddenly same page started to fail. It works fine on other browsers

```
Version Details: 
Window 10: 10586.218 
Edge Browser:25.10586.0.0 
Edge WebDriver: Microsoft WebDriver Fall 2015 Update
```

Answer (score 0):

The Edge WebDriver is not fully implemented. I appreciate you're essentially saying a keyword that works elsewhere is not working, however you're working with something that's in development:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/webdriver/details/

We made the call not to use this until it does become fully implemented; that might be something you should consider.

Comment: Thank you @shickey, that is helpful. One question though. I could not find that edge web driver is still under development. Can you please share where is it mentioned?

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/webdriver/details/